# Can I put +33 dBm through an 0402 capacitor/inductor?

Tags: power, rf, surface-mount

Consider the following capacitor [here](http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/TDK/C1005C0G1H330J050BA/?qs=%2Fha2pyFadujRsefd9%2FA%2F6GgdsbODW9JJqJaO5un4VQk8Qu0uJUxjMKruivwiqL4K) on Mouser (C1005C0G1H330J050BA). If my understanding is correct, the only power dissipated is due to the ESR - ideally, reactive elements dissipate no power (or is it no *average* power?).

The capacitor is 33pF rated at 50V. Let's suppose the frequency of interest is 915 MHz. Thus:

$$X_c = \frac{1}{2\pi f_c C} = \frac{1}{2\pi(915\times10^6)(33\times10^{-12})} = 5.271 \text{ }\Omega$$
$$I_{\text{peak}} = \frac{50 \text{ V}}{5.271 \text{ } \Omega} \approx 9.5 \text{ A}_{\text{peak}} \approx 6.72 \text{ A}_{\text{rms}}$$

If the current exceeds 6.72 A rms, the capacitor will be in bad shape. However, I would like to know if the capacitor can handle an RF power of +33 dBm (2 W)? My thinking is the following:

$$P = I^2 (ESR)$$

However, I only see the "low-ESR" claim and no actual number. Would this also depend on whether the capacitor was acting as a bypass or dc-blocking cap?

Comment: Go to tdk.com. Enter part number in search box. Press Enter. Click on search results. Scroll down. ESR is about 0.1 ohms.

Comment: Main lesson: don't trust distributor websites to have all the information on parts. Use the manufacturer website instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ideally, reactive elements dissipate no power (or is it no average
>   power?).

Reactive elements store and release power, but they don't dissipate it (ie. turn it into heat) *ever*. However in a circuit with unknown elements you cannot tell whether instantaneous power absorbed has been stored or dissipated until you average the power over a full cycle (power which was stored will be returned, but dissipated power is lost forever).

> would this also depend on whether the capacitor was acting as a bypass
>   or dc-blocking cap?

Depends on the particular circuit.

If it is blocking DC before a 50Ω resistive load then the rms current at 2W will be sqrt(2W/50Ω) = 0.2A. If the capacitor's ESR is 0.5Ω then it will dissipate 0.2A<sup>2</sup>*0.5Ω = 0.02W.

If it is a bypass capacitor then the current it has to pass could be less *or more* than the load current. In a high frequency rf circuit the bypass capacitor could be a major return path for signal current. To get 2W into 50Ω you need 10V rms or 28V peak to peak. If the supply voltage is less than 28V then the RF amplifier will have to produce more current to get 2W at the lower voltage, and the bypass current could be higher than the load current.

Answer (score 3):

Let's start by looking at an equivalent capacitor, whose datasheet actually gives some useful info, the [GRM1555C1H330JA01D](http://datasheet.octopart.com/GRM1555C1H330JA01D-Murata-datasheet-62317068.pdf).

The first plot is impedance versus frequency, and the minimum value, where capacitance and parasitic inductance cancel out, is the ESR, about 0.2 ohms.

More useful for power dissipation concerns is the last plot, of temperature rise versus current. At 1 A RMS, the temperature rise is already at least 25 degrees Celsius, so over 6 A would result in exceeding the rated temperature of the capacitor.

Comment: Assuming the 1 A rms (1.414 V peak) and 0.2 Ω ESR, would this mean the max power handling is: $$P = (1.414)^2 (0.2) = 400 \text{ mW}$$?

Comment: Power is based on the RMS value, so it would be (1 A)^2 * 0.2 ohm = 0.2 watt.

Comment: Ah yes. With regard to a bypass cap however, since it is in parallel, most of the current would flow along the signal path (only a little across the parallel cap due to ESR). If in series, however, I would need a larger cap to handle that power. Is this accurate?

Comment: @Biff, I think you'd better explain more what you're actually trying to do. It doesn't make much sense to connect this capacitor to a trace carrying a 900 MHz signal if you don't want that signal to drive current through the capacitor.

Answer (score 3):

33 dBm (2 watts) assumes a 50 ohm termination circuit and this means the current flow into that termination is \$\sqrt{2/50}\$ = 200 mA. So, find out the ESR (probably sub 0.1 ohms) and calculate power dissipated. It looks to me that if ESR is 0.1 ohms then power = 4 mW.

Nothing to worry about.